# Is there a way to filter out frequencies below a certain threshold in a message?

Tags: filter, signal-processing

I am writing a program in java and I have a signal that was modulated using FM. If the signal frequency is at 2800Hz it's a '0' and if the frequency is 7200Hz it's a '1'. Is this the right way to modulate it?

Also, is there a filter (in any language), that would go through the message and decrease the amplitude for frequencies below, say (7200+2800)/2Hz? Is there a better way to do FM demodulation?

Comment: There are plenty of filter design tools that give you coefficients for FIR or IIR filters, which are pretty easy to implement from the definition or to find a library for. But since you're just looking to identify 2 frequencies, I recommend looking into Goertzel's algorithm. You shouldn't really need to worry about filtering out the rest.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Katie's answer was spot on:

A very simple and efficient way to filter two frequencies is using Goertzel's algorithm, with plenty of implementations available out there:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm